# Can not load xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to load an xml file that is on my local system. But I always get Network_err. I do the following.

```
function LoadXmlDoc(dName)
{
    var xhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    try
    {       
        xhttp.open("GET", "file.xml", false);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    catch(e)
    {       
        window.alert("Unable to load the requested file.");
        return;
    }
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

How can I load an xml file that is on my system. all files are in same folder on my pc. Thanks

Comment: 1) What is the server url?
2) How you tried?
3) If you are tried using local file system ? . What is the system directory path ? . How you tried in browser?

Comment: open fire bug and see that you are getting to the correct location.

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: here, I make a folder. I put my html, javascript and xml file in that folder. and I run the html. where I make a button on whose event javascript function get called. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function XMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
xmlhttp.open("GET","yourfile",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Updated** due to simplify

Invoke `XMLDoc()` and pass your file uri instead of `yourfile`

**Note**: Don't forget to run this script on server

Comment: here, I make a folder. I put my html, javascript and xml file in that folder. and I run the html. where I make a button on whose event javascript function get called. Thanks

Comment: then how should I give it file name? because if I try to give just "file.xml", it gives the same error.

Comment: @Sarfraz you've to pass instead of `yourfile` file `URL` (where desired file is located)

Comment: Thanks @DaHaKa. can you please tell me what will be my file url? if it is in "C:\HTML" folder with name "file.xml". I am new to all this staff. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz Is this file in your root directory ?

Comment: Yes my all files (.html, .js and .xml) files are in this folder "C:\HTML". I am using windows xp if it matters. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz Which server are you using ?

Comment: I suppose I am using local server. I just create a html file and a javascript file. put them in a folder. and run the html file in browser.

Comment: @Sarfraz Like I see you haven't have server , in that case you can't accomplish this task. I suggest first understand what server is and how to install. If you are on windows , I suggest install wamp server , here is link => http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

you might need to give proper path of xml file like this

```
xhttp.open("GET", "file:///C:/file.xml", false);
        xhttp.send();
```

will do work fo ryou

full code will be like , Read more : [Loading XML with Javascript](http://www.steveborn.com/codenotes/LoadingXML.htm)

```
    var xmlDoc;
    var xmlloaded = false;

    function initLibrary()
    {
        importXML("file:///C:/file.xml");
    }

    function importXML(xmlfile)
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlfile, false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var ie = (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined');

            if (ie)
            {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                while(xmlDoc.readyState != 4) {};
                xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
                readXML();
                xmlloaded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                xmlDoc.onload = readXML;
                xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
                xmlloaded = true;
            }
        }

        if (!xmlloaded)
        {
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
            xmlhttp.send("");
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            readXML();
            xmlloaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I put my file in C directory. Run your given code but it still gives the same error. NETWORK_ERR

Answer (score 1):

You can't using `XHR` due security reasons.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files) is very complete answer for you.

Then ckeck the HTML5 API for local files: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/