# Read file:// URLs using Dojo 1.10

Tags: dojo

Is it possible to use Dojo 1.10 on a "file:///"-served web application with IE and/or Chrome?

Firefox doesn't seem to have a problem, however, I cannot get this to work IE 10+ or any recent version of Chrome.

Comment: Dojo has never claimed to support running from file:// URLs, because browsers typically place security restrictions on what scripts are allowed to do in pages loaded from the filesystem, e.g. to prevent accessing sensitive information it shouldn't.  I'd be very surprised if this was working for you in an older version of Dojo either, especially given that the legacy Dojo loader used sync XHR + eval, and XHR is one of the first things you will run into that are blocked.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11063963/237950) may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for te comments. Yeah... it was definitely working with 1.3, but in target browsers of IE <= 7 and FF 3.5 (we had a very specific browser target. I'll check the answer... thanks