# including other files besides js css etc. into html

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to read some information from a local XML document however i cant figure out how to do it.

I'm able to include js(and read data from them) css and all those kind of files but how do i read from an XML file or any other file.

The XML file is in the same directory as the js file so why shouldn't i be able to read it like any other js file?

I know it's possible to read files using nodejs but i'm trying to read the xml data and display it in a html page so it has to be client side.

// kan tijdelijk delayreport in js file zetten

```
var fs = require('browserify-fs'),
xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile('delayReport.xml', function(err, data) {
parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
    //console.dir(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
    console.log('Done');
    console.log(result);
    });
});

xhttp.open("GET", "delayReport.xml", true);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried, and your folder structure?

Comment: the js file and the xml are in the same folder and this is one of the thing i have tried "xhttp.open("GET", "delayReport.xml", true);"

Comment: @PaulBoon edit the whole code sample into your question, please. One line isn't enough to know what might be going wrong.  Also, just wondering: if you go to delayReport.xml in your browser, does it load the file?

Comment: yes that loads in but only if i use file:///path/to/file to get there

Comment: @PaulBoon OK good - I just wanted to make sure your server wasn't preventing access to it in general

Comment: while i could use a server isn't this somehow possible using only a static html file + a javascript file

Comment: @PaulBoon not over ajax

Comment: Is your server serving the XML file or not?  And are you trying to do this client side or through node.js?  If it's client side, why are you showing node.js code at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's not possible, because the XHMLRequest needs a server for asynchron communication. Only Browser that I know that loads local files offline is firefox. but maybe there are some workarounds, like discussed here [xmlhttprequest for local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files)

Comment: ok no xhmlrequests but maybe another way. you'd think it'd be possible since you can load js files from a static html page

Comment: Maybe you can convert the mxl into the json-format. You can add it like js with a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on the `file://` protocol.  Set up a local server and host your XML file statically through that.  Then you will be able to request your XML file with an XHR.  Fighting `file://` is going to give you headaches.