# reading local xml from javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to read a locally stored xml, and I want to read/write through javascript.
my code is as follows

```
function saveBaseValue()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  var XMLname="file:///C:/Users/setting.xml"
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",XMLname,false);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
   }

}
```

In this case, xmlhttp.responseXML is null.

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` `.onload` event handler to read results of asynchronous request. `xmlhttp.onload = function() {alert(xmlhttp.responseXML)};`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xmlhttprequest for local files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files)

Comment: guest271314 : what if I want a synchronous request?

Comment: this is a security issue, if any web can read your cookie file, so u can use <input type="file">

Comment: @pracheese What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve your goal by using the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function saveBaseValue()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  var XMLname="file:///C:/Users/setting.xml"  
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
   xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
      {    
         alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
      }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET",XMLname,false);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
 }
 saveBaseValue();
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>    
   <h1>Test</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

By default  your browser will not allow you to access this local file as this a security concern, however if you want to access it anyhow then close all chrome instance, go to command prompt, change the directory to where your chrome.exe is present and run below command.

```
.\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Note, with the latest Chrome, I get the following warning: `Web security may only be disabled if '--user-data-dir' is also specified with a non-default value.`