# AJAX request to local file system not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am working to dynamically create a UI from XML using jQuery. My jQuery is working in Firefox but in Chrome it's not working. It gives me this console error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

The following is my jQuery code which working on Firefox but not working on Google chrome:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file:///home/satendra/dndExamples/avisDnD/file.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('Tab').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('URL');
            var tab = $(this).attr('TabName');
            $("ul").append("<li><a href="+ id +">"+ tab +"</li>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `file:///` in the first place!? Set a local server.

Comment: The url should some thing like http url not file path

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Firefox allows the request because it accepts requests to the local file system (ie. the `file://` protocol) if they originate from there too. However Chrome denies all XMLHttpRequests to `file://` urls.

Note that you cannot make an AJAX request to the local file system from an external domain in either browser - it would be a *massive* security flaw if you could.

For this AJAX request to work in Chrome you need to make the request to a webserver. If you're on Windows you can easily install [IIS](http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on your local machine.

Note that it is possible to enable a setting in Google Chrome which allows requests to the local file system from the browser, but it's really not a good idea to use it. If you decide you want to go ahead and do this anyway, a guide can be found [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/).

Comment: it can be done, but will have to change the setting of chrome first, which is definitely not advisable but can be done

Comment: @Deep true, but that's not a good idea as it leaves your machine very vulnerable.

Comment: totally agree with you on this.

Comment: I added a note about it if the OP wants to, but it's entirely caveat emptor

Comment: @Deep : there have no way without creating web server ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Thank you sir for giving quick answer :)

Comment: @vibog no problem, glad to help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : But sir , Can I do that without webserver

Comment: if you want to by pass the chrome security than there is

Comment: You can use the setting I mentioned in Chrome, but as I stated, I would strongly suggest you use a webserver. If you're on windows it's literally a 2 minute job to install one.

Comment: @vibog , some else also wanted to do this for testing purpose , this is the answer i provided, here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288446/reading-local-xml-from-javascript/38289284#38289284

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Yes sir , You right I have no problem , your solution is wonderful . Actually I am working on microhttpd c++ server which is created by me . But that above jquery code just I made a simple , If now I integrate it with microhttpd server , will that work ? I don't now . That I want know microhttpd support that type request .

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _"as it leaves your machine very vulnerable"_ Can you describe how leaves machine vulnerable?

Comment: @guest271314 Because it means I can run JS code which can access any file on your local machine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  _"which can access any file on your local machine."_ How could you run code on another users machine  when user is at `file:` protocol which could access any file at users local machine?

Comment: The security setting is update on/in the Chrome browser itself!
(Global setting)

So doesnt matter if the user is trying to load a local file.. if they go a webstie, that has some js code in it.. it can access files in your local file system.