# Get data from JSON with XMLHtttpRequest

Tags: json, ajax

Can someone, please, explain to me, why in the code snippet below I get ***request.response == null***?
In my JSON file I have an array with some data, which I want to use further.

After spending a lot of time on finding a problem, I found that there is a problem with link. When I uploaded JSON file into web service and used a link from that, it works fine. But when I use a link to the file in my file system, it doesn't want to work.

```
let requestURL = "../sliderContent.json";

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = () => {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        let slidesContent = request.response;
        console.log(slidesContent);
        returnSlidesReducer(slidesContent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Add the two links please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX request to local file system not working in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344612/ajax-request-to-local-file-system-not-working-in-chrome)