# Open local server file using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to load locally stored data using plain javascript (no jquery for example) and then use it to display it in a table in html. My project structure looks like this:

root 
- js 
-- main.js 
- res 
-- data.csv 
- index.html

I tried using a `XMLHttpRequest`, but somehow I get status `0` when trying to load the file and when printing the response text it prints out nothing at all.

The following method is called using `window.onload`:

```js
var url = "file://../res/data.csv/";
varxmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: could be something related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344612/ajax-request-to-local-file-system-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX request to local file system not working in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344612/ajax-request-to-local-file-system-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: @LucaKiebel No, because I cant use jQuery

Comment: This has nothing to do with using jQuery or not using it. It doesn't work without some tweaks I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: please check this url [no-jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the file system through most browsers.

Even if it worked locally, it wouldn't work as soon as you put your page up on a server. This is because the client will be asking for a file that is local to itself, not the server.

Chrome may have something for you though:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/