# fail to find the path when running on the server using jsp

Tags: json, jsp

All the code below are written in jsp. When I start the server, it should alert the json type. When I run the code below not on the server, it actually works.  I suspect if is there something wrong with my file path. The path of the data.json is **C:\Users\fujimaro\Desktop\data.json** , otherwise I have no clue what could be wrong.

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.tutorials.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.*"%>
<%@page import="com.tutorials.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>noName</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascrip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    
        var arr = [];
        for(var x in mydata) {
            arr.push(mydata[x].name);
            arr.push(mydata[x].age);
        }
        for(var y in arr ) {
            alert(arr[y]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

***Json***

> data = '[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]';

Comment: Not sure what's going on here. Looks like you're loading the data.json through the < script >. That won't work. For what it's worth, the way you have the < script > pointing to the "data.json" file, it's a relative path, so the jsp page should be in the same folder as the jsp page on your server.

Comment: @bob Thank you for the reply.  You are right that I try to load the json data in the <script>.  My goal is to run I run the jsp, it will load the json, but i wonder why do you say it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSP (lets name it showJson.jsp) you loads javascript.js and data.json like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

In the `src` you give the filenames directly without prefix.
Therefore **the data.json, javascript.js and your showJson.jsp should be in the same folder**.

The project structure in glassfish 4 (java ee) look like this:

[image: java ee - glassfish 4 - project structure]

When the files are directly in `WebContent`-Folder, they can be access with these urls:

- http://localhost:8080/projectName/showJson.jsp
- http://localhost:8080/projectName/data.json
- http://localhost:8080/projectName/javascript.js

**But they should be first deployed**. The deployment is basically creating an [Web Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29) file projectName.war and moving it in a specific server folder. i.e.:

> C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\domain1

This projectName.war will be (in most cases) extracted to:

> C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\domain1\projectName_war