# Dynamic Text - Transparent and refreshed

Tags: html

I have a website with a photo as the background. I want to place text over the top of the photo that comes from a text file that is uploaded periodically.This can be a plain text file or HTML if needed.

The text may be:

> At `16:54:28 It's 19.7` degrees and we're playing Boney M - Daddy Cool

So I want this to refresh the page every, say, 30 seconds.

How do I put text from an external text file onto the page? The method needs to leave the photo as the background so iframe is no good unless there is a method that makes the frame transparent.

How do I refresh the dynamic text without refreshing the whole page?
Target site under development at www.surf-radio.net sat on GoDaddy.

> At `17:07:28 It's 18.3` degrees and we're playing Fatback Band - Spanish Hustle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xmlhttprequest for local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files)

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried?

Comment: I have no code I have tried, as I have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to **refresh** a single element in HTML:

```
<p id="transparenttext">Hello World!</p>
<script>document.getElementById("transparenttext").innerHTML = "New text!";</script>
```

To make the text **transparent**, you can type `#transparenttext{opacity: 0.5;}` in your CSS file.

And change the upper JS to:

```
document.getElementById("transparenttext").innerHTML = client;
```

To load a file you can go to this post: [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)